# Visual Studio 2013 seems not to understand javascript syntax

Tags: javascript, arrays, visual-studio

I Have a Problem while porting a large old DHTML application that ran on COM+ to dotnet (C#). I want to keep the large amount of javascript "as is". I already tested the old version on IE11 and all other current browsers and there it runs just fine! (and I use NO JQUERY!)

Now here comes the problem: 
The Visual Studio 2013 debug environment seems to refuse to understand normal javascript syntax. Simply put, it refuses to understand that in javascript one can do something like this with a global array:

```
var SomeArray = new Array();
function VulTitelLijst(){
    try {
        SomeArray["aa"] = "bb";
    } catch (err) { alert(err.description);}
    //etc. 
}
```

where I run this code in the Visual Studio 2013 debugger goes into the catch mode and reports that "I can not set a value to a non identified entity". THis error is produced by the browser. However the above is quite valid javascript

Other actions on the global array, like "push", etc. are also not allowed.

Addition: What DOES work is this:

```
var SomeArray = new Array();
function VulTitelLijst(){
    var arHlp = new Array();
    try {
        arHlp["aa"] = "bb";
        SomeArray = arHlp;
    } catch (err) { alert(err.description);}

    testArray();

    //etc. 
}

function testArray(){
    var tmpTest = SomeArray["aa"];
    alert('tmpTest = ' + tmpTest);
}
```

Now there are a number of strange things about this:
1.) this whole business with intermediate arrays is not necessary when running the code normally in the browser. So why is that necessary when running in the browser from VS2013?
2.) When running from IE11 in debug mode from VS 2013 it seems to somehow not understand or confuse the rules about context and namespace in javascript (this is the impression I get .. ) 
3.) If it does NOT recognize my global Array from inside routine, one should expect that it would not recognize the thing at all in there, however that is not case, because inside the routine I can copy to and from the array as a whole, but to parts of it??? 
4.) The problematic behaviour is caused by VS2013 (it runs fine in the normal context), but the error is generated by IE11 (in dutch) 
5.) why does this problem only occur in the browser (IE11) when in debug mode???

I am not a novice in javascript (been doing this for years without a hitch..) whats going on?
To me this tastes of a bug in VS 2013?? 

By the way, EXCUSE the comment below, they must seem like gibberish, I was a bit over-ambitious about entering code in these comments...

Comment: First of all. I would advice you to install Visual Studio in english. It is so much easier to search for errors when they are reported back in english (I am danish and always run my IDE in english for that reason). It would be lot easier to help if you could post the exact error in english.

Comment: You're right, only its not Visual Studio (English) which produces the error message but IE11 (which came pre-installed with the PC). However I dont want to change the setup at this moment, because I am working on a time-constrained project.

Comment: Following last comment: However I did find a practical solution, from a hunch I already had, that this has something to do with Visual Studio mixing up te rules for context and namespace between it own environment and the invironment of the browser, which runs javascript. This seems to be support by my finding that the following code does work:  var SomeArray = new Array();
function VulTitelLijst(){
    try {
        SomeArray["aa"] = "bb";
    } catch (err) { alert(err.description);}
    alert(987);
}

Comment: Sorry, push the ENTER too quickly, this is the code that DOES work,

   var SomeArray = new Array();
   function VulTitelLijst(){
       var arHlp = new Array();
       try {
           arHlp["aa"] = "bb";
       } catch (err) { alert(err.description);}
       SomeArray = arHlp;
   } 
   function TestArray() {
      var tmpTest = SomeArray["aa"];
      alert('tmpTest = ' + tmpTest);
   }

which is strange, because in javascript one should not need such a intermediate array. 
And even stranger because the error is produced by IE11, but only run from the Visual Studio 2013 IDE??? A BUG in VS??

Comment: SORRY for the latest additions, it does not seem to display formatted code correctly..